# C++: Does current namespace override other namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm writing a library with contents:

```cpp
namespace david {
  typedef enum {
    BAR
  } CommonEnum;

  class Foo {
    void fooBar () {
      std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

and let's say a user writes the file

```cpp
typedef enum {
  BAR = 1
} CommonEnum;

#include <david.h>

Foo myFoo();

myFoo.fooBar();
```

What will be printed? If `0` will be printed, is that *reliable*? I know I could just prefix my use of `BAR` in `david::Foo` such that it reads `david::BAR` and that would answer the question for sure (which is what I'm currently doing) but it's getting quite verbose and I'm trying to stick to the 80-character limit which means my code is getting increasingly difficult to read.

Comment: *"What will be printed?"* - A question back: What *was* printed when you tried this? Is that the only question, or are you looking for a citation from the standard that removes any doubts you have that what you witnessed is definitive?

Comment: It will first complain about the missing semicolon in `Foo`'s definition, then it will tell you "`Foo` was not declared in this scope" and then, when you fix that, "request for member `fooBar` in `myFoo`, which is of non-class type `david::Foo()`", and finally it will complain that `fooBar` is private.

Answer (score 0):

Having the class `Foo` and the enum `BAR` in `namespace david`

```
void fooBar () {
    std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
}
```

will resolve `BAR` to the innermost applicable scope. Thus

```
typedef enum {
    BAR = 1
} CommonEnum;
```

won't *"override"* the definition from `namespace david`.